# Can't find my table in sqlite after creating it and streaming data to the db file

Tags: python, sqlite, tweepy

this is my first time using sqlite, I've only worked on MySQL before. I have a program where I stream live twitter tweets and store them in a db. The program creates a database, and then starts running tweepy to fetch the data from twitter. I'm having trouble trying to print out my data for data exploration from my db file, `twitter.db`. I do however see the tweets stream real-time on my console, I just cannot seem to call the data from the db.

Below is my database.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')

c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    try:
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sentiment(unix REAL, tweet TEXT, sentiment REAL)")  
        c.execute("CREATE INDEX fast_unix ON sentiment(unix)")
        c.execute("CREATE INDEX fast_tweet ON sentiment(tweet)")
        c.execute("CREATE INDEX fast_sentiment ON sentiment(sentiment)")
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
create_table()
```

After I run the program once, I hashtag the `def create_table()` function out to allow the flow of data to stream without having the program run another create_table(). Below is how I stream the data to my db.

```
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            data = json.loads(data)
            tweet = unidecode(data['text'])
            time_ms = data['timestamp_ms']

            analysis = TextBlob(tweet)

            sentiment = analysis.sentiment.polarity
            print(time_ms, tweet, sentiment)
            c.execute("INSERT INTO sentiment (unix, tweet, sentiment) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                  (time_ms, tweet, sentiment))
            conn.commit()

        except KeyError as e:
            print(str(e))
        return(True)
```

The streaming from twitter API seems to work well, however when I want to print out my rows for data exploration and check if the data is being stored, I receive this error: `OperationalError: no such table: sentiment`. The code below produces said error:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM sentiment")

print(c.fetchall())
```

When I run `c.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master")` ...I get a `[]` printed on screen. Which I assume and know that something is very wrong. What is wrong with the code above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you executing the scripts from the same directory?

If not sure I suggest to write in both scripts

```
import os
print("I am in following directory: ", os.getcwd())
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')
```

instead of

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')
```

and check if both really look in the same directory for `twitter.db`

If they do, then go to the command line change into this directory and type

```
sqlite3 twitter.db
```

and type then

```
.tables
```

and look what tables will be listed.
you can then even type queries (if the table exists) to check in more detail

```
SELECT * FROM sentiment;
```

Comment: Such a silly error I made, you correct in assuming I wasn't running the commands in the same directory. I thought it was a user-access issue, thank you so much for catching that.

Comment: It is a typical Sqlite issue. With other databases the current working directory doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

I think [gelonida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/858675/gelonida) is right on the money and comand-line sqlite3 is your friend.

I slightly modified your code and it works fine when the db is in the same location:

```
import os
import sqlite3

os.remove('twitter.db')
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    try:
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sentiment(unix REAL, tweet TEXT, sentiment REAL)")
        c.execute("CREATE INDEX fast_unix ON sentiment(unix)")
        c.execute("CREATE INDEX fast_tweet ON sentiment(tweet)")
        c.execute("CREATE INDEX fast_sentiment ON sentiment(sentiment)")
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
create_table()

def on_data():
    try:
        tweet = 'text'
        time_ms = 123.2
        sentiment = 1.234
        print(time_ms, tweet, sentiment)
        c.execute("INSERT INTO sentiment (unix, tweet, sentiment) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            (time_ms, tweet, sentiment))
        conn.commit()
    except KeyError as e:
        print(str(e))
    return(True)
on_data()

conn.close()

# Now check the result
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM sentiment")
print(c.fetchall())
```

running it prints:

```
123.2 text 1.234
[(123.2, 'text', 1.234)]
```

Comment: Yes you both were correct on solving my issue, thank you. Silly me!